# Can't change icon when I click it and save text to state - React

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I have couple links with add to fav icon.

When I click the icon I want to change star icon to another star and get links name to state by hooks

far fa-star  to  fas fa-star

I use arrow function components by the way

```
{reposList?.name !== "Error" &&
  reposList?.map(repo => (
    <>
        <div className="col-6 g-3 ">
        <div className="border rounded-pill px-3 py-2 bg-secondary  ">
        <i 
        class="far fa-star pe-2" role={ 'button'}

        ></i> 
        <a
            target="_blank"
            href={repo?.html_url}
            className="text-light"
          >
            {repo?.name} 
          </a>
          <strong className="text-light ps-2">({repo?.language})</strong>
      </div>
    </div>
          
        
    </>
  ))}
```

Comment: im confused, are you trying to replace the existed icon with another one on click?

Comment: Yeah also want to get the name to useState

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can update your state onClick, and according to the state, it will render or change that icon.

assuming that `<star/>` and `<fullStar/>` are the icons we will use.

You will create a state using `useState` as follows.

```
const [starState,setStarState] = useState(false);
```

and now on the icon tag or the button tag, we will add `onClick` calling `setStarState`

```
<star onClick={()=> setStarState(!starState)}/>
```

Also, you will need to check the state before rendering, thats how it will change.

```
startState ? 
<star onClick={()=> setStarState(!starState)}/> :
<fullStar onClick={()=> setStarState(!starState)}/>
```

this will render the icon depending on the state.

BUT ...........
In case you are dealing with `Array of Objects` which you should in your case, so your state should be something like this

```
const [arr, setArr] = useState([
{
  name: "A",
  isActive: false,
},
{
  name: "B",
  isActive: false,
},
{
  name: "C",
  isActive: false,
},
{
  name: "D",
  isActive: false,
},
]);
```

Now you want to update only 1 property in that array.

```
const handleChange = (el) => {
let oldArr = [...arr];
let index = oldArr.findIndex((obj) => obj.name === el.name);
oldArr[index].isActive = !oldArr[index].isActive;

setArr(oldArr);
```

};

where you call `handleChange()` function on your `onClick` Button and pass the current `item` or `el` in my case to it.

```
 <button onClick={() => handleChange(el)}>Change state</button>
```

Comment: It worked thanks but its in loop so when i click one of them it changes all 10 button icons

Comment: @FatihCan check the udpated answer, i added how you can deal with Array of objects which you need in your case, each element should have an `inActive` property to know if the element is either active or not.